# Xpath con-cat is possible with reference to List<WebElement> object in selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Scenario with Example:**

- 10 Different Row in Table (e.g. //a[@class='*******'] ).
- Need to Retrieve different Value from each Row
- Retrieving it using List
- In given example, Temp1 getting executed and iterate as required, As information need to retrieve from the same  and got it through getAttribute(" ").
- Need to retrieve Temp2 value which is dependent on object *findList*.  findSubInfo is having Following Siblings from mainList. Its only addition on following siblings in to List exa.(findList).

**Issue is :**

- If I execute 1st provision, as independent node, It always retrieve first row's value. (Which is Obvious)
- If I execute 2nd provision, with xpath + List object using con-cat it throws xpath Syntax issue.

**Question :**
How can retrieve all information from object's siblings, where object `List<WebElement> findList` is pointing ?

**Trial :**

```
By mainList = By.xpath("//a[@class='*******']");
By findSubInfo = By.xpath("//a[@class='*****']//following::div[@class='****']");

    List<WebElement> findList = driver.findElements(mainList);

        for (WebElement webElement : findList ) {
            if (webElement.isDisplayed()) {

            String temp1= "Info1:" + webElement.getAttribute("ng-href");                    
            String temp2= "Info2: " + driver.findElement(findSubInfo).getText();
            }
        }
```

OR

```
String mainList "//a[@class='*******']";
String findSubInfo = "//following::div[@class='****']";

     List<WebElement> findList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(mainList));

        for (WebElement webElement : findList ) {
            if (webElement.isDisplayed()) {

            String temp1= "Info1:" + webElement.getAttribute("ng-href");    
            String temp2= "Info2: " + driver.findElement(By.xpath(webElement + findSubInfo )).getText();
            }
        }
```

Exception Details:

> SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string
>   '[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (3208ef0a2ffd32812c33e159291eebe4)] ->
>   xpath: //a[@class='noDecoration
>   addPointer']]//following::div[@class='assignedAccountMasterAddress']'
>   is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: `//a[@class='noDecoration addPointer']]/` there is an extra closing square bracket

Comment: @Andersson Yes its from object webElement itself.

Comment: @IshitaShah, kindly paste HTML as well

Comment: @GauravGenius HTML is not matter in this situation. Exception is obvious, because I have con cat object webElement with findSubInfo(Which is String). And that is causing syntax issue from webElement side.

Comment: Yes I understand, i'm asking for html so that I can suggest workaround

Comment: @GauravGenius HTML is included in first 2 line of code as Xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search for element with related XPath starting from current element (`webelement`), try

```
# Note that it should start with the dot
String findSubInfo = "./following::div[@class='****']";
# use webElement.findElement instead of driver.findElement. No XPath concatenations needed
String temp2= "Info2: " + webElement.findElement(By.xpath(findSubInfo)).getText();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've changed `"//following::div[@class='****']"` to `"./following::div[@class='****']"`?

Comment: It worked. I just forgot to add dot. I have add it and it worked. Thanks a lot.